# Jack does not have a "connect" option, how do I fix this?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, midi

I have been trying to configure jack on my laptop. I think I found part of the problem, and then ran into a new one. On jack, there is no "Connect" option. "Start" is missing as well. There are three menu options on the main screen; quit, setup, and about. Hopefully after I fix this issue I will be all set. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem for this. It is in a drop down menu under the qjackctl icon.